# Why is incrementing and assigning to a reference, not change the value?

Tags: c++, reference

I am not able to understand, why the output of the code is not what I was expecting.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int m = 2, n = 6;
    int &x = m;
    int &y = n;
    m = x++; 
    x = m++;
    n = y++;
    y = n++;
    cout<< m << " " << n; 
    return 0; 
}
```

> I was expecting `4 8`

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: since `x` is reference to `m` this line `m = x++;` is same as `m = m++;` and this is undefined behavior.

Comment: @MarekR Not from c++17, I think.

Comment: Clangs undefined behavior sanitizer doesn't finds anything https://godbolt.org/z/o9a1rv

Comment: MSVC gives different answer https://rextester.com/GJWG22689

Comment: You should get together with [Rahul Singh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13559533/rahul-singh) as you both are working on the [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64068344/explain-me-to-understand-the-output-of-following-code).

Answer (score 6):

This line:

```
m = x++;
```

is equivalent to:

```
x = x++;
```

since `m` is a reference to `x`.

From c++17, the right hand side is evaluated first, resulting in 2. Then `x` is incremented to 3. Then the assignment of the right hand side value to the left hand side is done. But this uses the old value of the right hand side, which is 2. So the above statement effectively does nothing.

Before c++17,

```
m = x++;
```

is undefined behavior.

Comment: Checking my knowledge here: Before C++17 was it undefined because assignment and increment were both sequenced after return, but not sequenced against each others?

Comment: @Frodyne Pretty much. Here's a useful [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points) that covers this in detail.

Comment: I've run this code using msvc on my machine and with switch `/std:c++14` it produces `4 8` and for  `/std:c++17` it produces result `2 6`.

Comment: @MarekR For c++17, I explained the result in the answer. Pre c++17 it's UB so don't worry about it :)

Comment: @cigien I know, this was just experimental proof. Anyway IMO this should fail during build (it is C++14 constexpr with UB): https://godbolt.org/z/7fsTMG.

Comment: @MarekR That's a good point. Seems like a reasonable question to ask :) If you don't, and I can't find an answer on SO, I'll ask it myself.

Comment: What is funny when I running https://godbolt.org/z/7fsTMG on my machine with msvc (19.25.28614) I got answer `2 8`, but when I just remove last `constexpr` from it it produces answer `4 8` (same build options).

Comment: I don't understand what you're confused by. Of course UB could end up showing different results (it could do that every time you run the same program). The only interesting thing here is why `constexpr` doesn't diagnose it.

Comment: `constexpr` should be UB free. Compiler should file an error in case UB is present in `constexpr`. So this is bug in msvc for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Notice how the operators are post-increment and not pre-increment... You're basically doing nothing.

`m = x++;` means that increment x (i.e. m) but return the old value of x (i.e. m). Assignment takes place after the increment and return of old value and the old value is what ends up getting assigned. So, you end up essentially with a bunch of self-assignments.